# load gif into QMovie object from data (no file)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, gif

I have read through many questions, most of which not on this site, and they all mention QMovie must be called with a file name, like this

```
anim = QtGui.QMovie("Filename.gif")

#or

self.movie = QMovie(filename, QByteArray(), self) #self is implied a class/super
```

but I was wondering if there was any way to load this from data directly, similar to QPixMap:

```
Img = QtGui.QPixMap()
Img.loadFromData("\x00\x5f\xaa\x3a... ...\xff")

#or
data = open("file.gif", "rb").read() #So you get what I mean
Img.loadFromData(data)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `QMovie` constructor can take a `QIODevice` as first argument, so the gif data can be loaded via a `QBuffer`:

```
a = QtCore.QByteArray(data)
b = QtCore.QBuffer(a)
b.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
m = QtGui.QMovie(b, 'GIF')
```