# Pyqt4 QMovie FFMPEG decoder

Tags: python, video, pyqt4, qbytearray, qiodevice

I'm quite new to pyqt. So please forgive any misconcepts I might have.

I have trouble to load video directly to QMovie using:
`__init__ (self, QString fileName, ...)`
QMovie itself seems quite picky when it comes to supporting (decoding) Video formats.

This is why I want to decode the VideoFiles using FFMPEG, store the frames into a QIODevice and feed the device to QMovie using:
`__init__ (self, QIODevice device, ...)`

This code uses FFMPEG to decode a Video file and stores the first 20 frames into a QIODevice stream as JPGs. This QIODevice is fed to the QMovie.

Great! the QMovie plays at full speed...
But.. only once ...
and the `QMovie.frameCount()` returns just `1` frame instead of 20... (when queried before `QMovie.start()`)

Using PyQt4, imageio, numpy

```
print('>> FFMPEG Loading file : '+videoFile)

# Use FFMPEG to decode Video through imageio
self.vid=imageio.get_reader(str(videoFile),  'ffmpeg')

# Init QIODevice
byte_array = QtCore.QByteArray()
self.buf = QtCore.QBuffer()
self.movie= QtGui.QMovie(parent)

# Populate 20 Frames Stream 
i=0
self.buf.open(QtCore.QIODevice.Append)

#Sample 20 Frames from videoFile
while i<20:
    # decode / read to rgb24 Frame
    npArray_RGB888 = self.vid.get_data(i).astype(np.uint8)

    # Actually 'append' the Frame data to the Stream as JPG
    npArray_RGB888.save(self.buf, 'JPG')

    #print(' == == '+str(self.buf.data().size()))
    #print(' == == '+str(buf.data()))            

    i+=1

# Close the Stream 
self.buf.close()     

# Load the QIODecvice buffer in QMovie   
# self.movie.setFileName(videoFile) # To decode with QMovie directly
self.movie = QtGui.QMovie(self.buf, 'jpg', self)

print('>>>   FrameCount : '+str(self.movie.frameCount()))

self.movie.start()
```

Why is the framecount `1` instead of 20?
What am I doing wrong?

Is there a more direct way to store FFMPEG result data into QIODevice?
Prehaps loading the videoFile at once into the QIODevice instead of each frame individually?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you understand what the `QMovie` class is intended for? I suggest you read the [detailed description](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmovie.html#details) more carefully.

Comment: I think so... What do you mean exactly? When  the `__init__ (self, QString fileName, ...)` works (for me only with GIFs), it does EXACTLY, perfectomundo what I need.              I need more than simple playback.I must be able to jump to any frame at any time, browse the frames forward/backwards, change speed etc.     I could write everything myself, decoding / reading in separate threads etc...   Dynamically caching frames underneath the mousepointer on a sliderbar before it gets clicked, ...        It seems to me that QMovie handles all this very stuff neatly.

Comment: I cannot put it any more clearly than what is already written there.

Comment: QMovie does exactly what I need when initialized with a filepath.
But it plays only 2% of the vidéo formats. 
You can decode videos yourself and initialize a QMovie with a QIODevice. 99% there before hitting a wall...
Motivation @ 0%.

Comment: So you're just going to stubbornly continue trying to use a class which is clearly not designed for displaying video content. No wonder your motivation is at zero percent ...

Comment: What should I use? Its called qmovie and does what I need.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27214178/load-gif-into-qmovie-object-from-data-no-file

Comment: An animated gif is not a video. Read the article I linked to in my first comment. And by "read", I mean more than just skimming the first sentence.

Comment: I read it 10 times trying to understand what you mean. Is flipping QPixmap's the sollution? Using phonon? I need to make a videoplayer for animators (finetuning lipsync etc ) where you can scrub through etc. Browsing / synching audio is no problem.

Comment: The `QMovie` class only displays images, not videos: see [QMovie.supportedFormats](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmovie.html#supportedFormats). Loading an image from an `QIODevice`, is like (in python terms) passing in a file-object rather than a path. Either way, you need to supply data from an *animated image format* (such as a gif), rather than from a video format.

Comment: PS: if you can upgrade to PyQt5, the QtMultimedia module has all the functionality you need (see: [Working with Low Level Video Frames](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/videooverview.html#working-with-low-level-video-frames)).

Comment: Thx. QMovie is a quite misleading name though